# ReSharper function multiline parameters indentation

Tags: c++, resharper

I want ReSharper to indent my function parameters like this when i hit enter after `int b` parameter:

```
void function(int a, int b,
              int x, ...) {
}
```

but I can't reach it with options `Call arguments` and `First call argument by '('` nevertheless in preview of `Options` window it looks correct. What should I do?

Update: if I do `Cleanup selection` - everything ok, indentation as I want to, bun not when I hit `enter`. Why?

Comment: Check the state of the `ReSharper | Options | Environment | Editor | Behavior | Smart indent on Enter` option.

Comment: yes, it's enabled

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable `First call argument by '('` and enable `Call arguments` only. Check also to have chosen the right program language.

Comment: yes, that's what I have for now and the ReSharper idents new line with 4 spaces